# What does the phrase “get me bloody please” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the phrase **get me bloody please** mean? Here is some context from a song :

> Get me, get me bloody, please get me bloody
>
> You can get down on your knees if you're naughty

It sounds for me like he wants to get a pleasure in the first line.

Comment: Could you reference the song here? More context is required to understand the meaning.

Comment: Often only the author of the lyric knows the intended meaning, at times though even they don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the song you're referring to (X - Poppy), the singer is expressing a desire to be covered in blood.

As with many song lyrics it may be possible to infer some deeper meaning, but that meaning would be artistic interpretation rather than linguistic.